# How to force a clean git working repository in a makefile?

Tags: git, makefile, working-directory

I'm trying to make a `deploy` command in my Makefile, which simply overwrites to the branch `deployment` and then pushes this branch to `origin`.

However, the command must stop/fail with an error message when the working tree is not empty.

Something like the following:

```
deploy:

    status=$(git status --porcelain)
    test "x$(status)" = "x"
    git branch -f deployment
    git push origin deployment
```

Unfortunately, this test on and status variable do not seem to function as wanted.

How would one achieve this? Am I indeed supposed to use `test`?

Comment: In a makefile, each of those commands will run in a separate shell.   Also $(status) will be the value of the variable status in the makefile, not in the shell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `git diff-index` to check if the repo is dirty:

```
deploy:
        git diff-index --quiet HEAD 
        git branch -f deployment
        git push origin deployment
```

If you want to check shell variables in a makefile, you need to ensure that you check the value of the variable in the same shell as the one in which it is set.  Make will invoke each command in a separate shell, so you would need to do something like:

```
deploy:
        @status=$$(git status --porcelain); \
        if test "x$${status}" = x; then \
            git branch -f deployment; \
            git push origin deployment; \
        else \
            echo Working directory is dirty >&2; \
        fi
```

Note the double '$', the semi-colon, and the line continuations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not quite sure whether I should now use the first code or the second. When using the second, I get `make: *** [deploy] Error 1` but it doesn't actually tell me what goes wrong where. How would I output the value of `status` after the first line to see if it's correct? Also, why are you using `&&` for all but the first line?

Comment: The && are not really necessary.  Using the && makes the shell short circuit and not invoke the git branch/git push, but leaving them out would cause make to abort after the test and not invoke the branch/push.  I just put them in for variety.  To see the value of status, add the line "echo $$status; \" after the line that sets status.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I probably need to learn more about Makefiles and the shell. Could you maybe tell me how to output an error message like "working directory is not clean" when the test fails?

Comment: I'm afraid that's returning `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.` I cannot make sense of this. What are the 3 stars, and what separator is missing?

Comment: Update: I didn't know that Make only supports tabs, I was using spaces as indents. Sorry, thanks for the help.

Comment: Why is it that you use `;` after every line, doesn't the newline indicate that the command is finished? When must you use `;` in a Makefile?

Comment: @Tom  In a Makefile, each line is invoked in a different shell.  To run a multi-line shell command, it must be written as a one-liner so you cannot use newline as a delimiter, but must use semi-colons.  The line-continuations are for human readability only, and make will pass the whole stanza as a single line to the shell for interpretation.

Comment: Hmm.  I can't understand why I wrote "The line-continuations are for human readability only".  Perhaps that was referring to a previous edit.  That is the silliest thing I've ever written, and even 6.5 years ago I would have been aware of that.  That is utterly wrong; the line continuations are absolutely necessary to ensure that Make runs all the commands in the same shell.